# Prove or disprove isomorphic graphs

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We have no diagram, just a presentation.
Symbols $\{a,b\}$.
Rules: $(a^2 =1, b^2 =1, aba =bab)$.
Everything is to be deduced from these rules only, here every word is equivalent to exactly one of $(1,a, b, ab, ba, aba)$.
Nickname for this system is $S_3$.
Prove or disprove $S_3= D_3$  ($S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$).
if not, give out a mathematical reason.
If so, give out an actual isomorphism: that is one to one and onto function T from the set 
$(1,a,b,ab,ba, aba)$ to the set $\{(1,r,r^2, f, fr, fr^2)\}$ such that $T(w_1 w_2) = T(w_1) T(w_2)$ for all words $w_1$ and $w_2$ in $(1,a,,b,ab,ba,aba)$.

please help

Comment: Graphs? Are you sure that you don’t mean *groups*?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I do not know how to classify it. I studied the stuff from graph-theory portion, so I think it's appropriate when post it here

Comment: It should be classified as "group theory" instead of "graph theory."  Even if this problem came from graph theory, your presentation of it leaves no trace of that evolution and you've given it as a pure group theory problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write down the orders for each element in your $S_3$ and $D_3$ groups.  If the list of elements differs, you have a non-isomorphism.

If the list of orders matches up, then you know that the elements of order 1 will map to each other (and there is only 1 of those), that the elements of order 2 will map to each other, and same with the elements of order 3.  (And I think it's pretty clear there are no elements of order 6 here.)

You could also "cheat" a little and look up the fact that there are only 2 groups of order 6, one abelian (the cyclic group) and one not ($D_3$) and that sort of gives the answer away.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learn from your instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Another explicit map: Take $T(a)=f,\ T(b)=fr.$ Then the others are determined by the laws in $D_3$. $$T(ab)=ffr=r$$ $$T(ba)=frf=ffr^2=r^2$$ $$T(aba)=ffrf=rf=fr^2.$$ And of course $T(1)=1$. There is still the matter of checking products on words are preserved.

Comment: It's very helpful. Thank you very much. To a new comer like me, the explicit map is understandable.

Comment: There may be some differences, as I did compositions (multiplications) left-to-right, and I also used $rf=fr^2$. Depending on the convention used in your course/source text, they may do compositions right-to-left or have the relations on $D_3$ differently written.

Answer (score 0):

Take $T(ab)=r, T(aba)=f$.  Note that $(ab)^2=ba, (ab)^3=1$, and $(aba)^2=1$, which translates to $f^2=1$.  Note that $b=(ab)(aba)$, and $a=(aba)(ab)$.  Hence the rules $a^2=b^2=1$ translate to $(rf)^2=(fr)^2=1$.  Lastly, $aba=bab$ is equivalent to $(ab)^3=1$ under the previous rules (multiply on the right by $bab$), which translates to $r^3=1$.  These are exactly the defining relations for $D_3$.

Comment: The rule you gave out teach me how to prove the last part of the question. Appreciate all help.